# Azure publish: Failed to update API in Azure

Tags: c#, azure, swagger, azure-web-app-service

Im trying to publish my .net3.1 webapp on Azure from Visual Studio.

Visual studio fails on 'Starting to update your API' step, this is the output from visual studio:

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: WebApplication_XXX, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
1>WebApplication_XXX -> C:\Users\YYYY\source\repos\WebApplication_XXX\WebApplication_XXX\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\WebApplication_XXX.dll
1>Done building project "WebApplication_XXX.csproj".
2>------ Publish started: Project: WebApplication_XXX, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
WebApplication_XXX -> C:\Users\YYYY\source\repos\WebApplication_XXX\WebApplication_XXX\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\WebApplication_XXX.dll
npm install
npm run build -- --prod
> webapplication_xxx@0.0.0 build C:\Users\YYYY\source\repos\WebApplication_XXX\WebApplication_XXX\ClientApp
> ng build "--prod"

Generating ES5 bundles for differential loading...
ES5 bundle generation complete.
....
Publish Succeeded.
Web App was published successfully https://xxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
Starting to update your API
Generating swagger file to 'C:\Users\YYYY\source\repos\WebApplication_XXX\WebApplication_XXX\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\swagger.json'.
Failed to update your API in Azure.
```

I then check Azure portal and find some error in 'Create API or Update API' json

```
...
"properties": {
    "statusCode": "BadRequest",
    "serviceRequestId": "*****",
    "statusMessage": "{\"error\":{\"code\":\"ValidationError\",\"message\":\"One or more fields contain incorrect values:\",\"details\":[{\"code\":\"ValidationError\",\"target\":\"representation\",\"message\":\"Parsing error(s): JSON is valid against no schemas from 'oneOf'. Path 'securityDefinitions.Bearer', line 2841, position 15.\"},{\"code\":\"ValidationError\",\"target\":\"representation\",\"message\":\"Parsing error(s): The input OpenAPI file is not valid for the OpenAPI specificate https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md (schema https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/schemas/v2.0/schema.json).\"}]}}",
    "eventCategory": "Administrative",
    "entity": "/subscriptions/*****/resourceGroups/XXX/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/WebApplicationXXXapi/apis/WebApplicationXXX",
    "message": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis/write",
    "hierarchy": "*****"
},
...
```

So I open the generated swagger.json file from `'C:\Users\YYYY\source\repos\WebApplication_XXX\WebApplication_XXX\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\swagger.json'` in swagger editor and get the same error:

```
Structural error at securityDefinitions.Bearer
should have required property 'type'
missingProperty: type
```

because the Security Definitions Bearer is empty in the json file

```
securityDefinitions:
  Bearer: {
  }
```

if I make the following change in in the swagger editor it gets happy:

```
securityDefinitions:
  Bearer: {
    type: apiKey,
    name: "JWT Authentication",
    in: "header"
  }
```

In my application Startup.cs I got:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "XXX API", Version = "v1" });
    var securityScheme = new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        Name = "JWT Authentication",
        Description = "Enter JWT Bearer token **_only_**",
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
        Scheme = "bearer", // must be lower case
        BearerFormat = "JWT",
        Reference = new OpenApiReference
        {
            Id = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
            Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme
        }
    };
    c.AddSecurityDefinition(securityScheme.Reference.Id, securityScheme);
    c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
    {
        {securityScheme, new string[] { }}
    });
});
```

what is it Im missing? Shouldnt the code in Startup.cs add the securityDefinition when generating the swagger.json file?

Comment: I have checked my frameworks. I have a JWT auth working, thats is not my problem I can build and run my app localy. I tried to generate the swagger.json file by running the 'dotnet swagger tofile' command. If I run it without the '--serializeasv2' argument the generated json is valid in swagger editor. SwaggerUI works when running localy.

Comment: But the Azure publishing tries to generate a swagger file with the  '--serializeasv2' argument. I can upload a V3 swagger file to Azure API Management and It seems to work fine. I get my end-points and no validation errors. I dont know what to do next? Switch cloud service?

Answer (score 5):

We have the same problem. For now we have used a workaround with disabling update the api during publish. (I use VS2022 and .net6.0)
In the PublishProfiles/...pubxml change the parameter UpdateApiOnPublish to false.

```
<UpdateApiOnPublish>false</UpdateApiOnPublish>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is going to be applicable for everyone and it's using different markup but I found I got this issue when I have a path parameter of a class type.

This fails

`` [OpenApiParameter(name: "countryCode", Type = typeof(Country), In = ParameterLocation.Path, Summary = "Country for the customer", Description =` "Must be a valid country, eg UK")] ``

This works but is not what I want as `string` is too generic.

`` [OpenApiParameter(name: "countryCode", Type = typeof(string), In = ParameterLocation.Path, Summary = "Country for the customer", Description =` "Must be a valid country, eg UK")] ``

The solution was the adding the `Required` attribute.

`` [OpenApiParameter(name: "countryCode", Type = typeof(Country), In = ParameterLocation.Path, Summary = "Country for the customer", Description =` "Must be a valid country, eg UK", Required = true)] ``

Answer (score -1):

Can you check if there is any target framework missing also check your NuGet packages dependency.

JwtSecurityTokenHandler class which generated a token needs to be implemented. To understand the correct workflow for JWT implementation check this [JWT Authentication Tutorial with Example API](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/10/11/aspnet-core-3-jwt-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api#projectstructure).