# Failed to publish on Azure App Service while Generating swagger file

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I am getting this error when I try to publish my ASP.NET Web API to Azure App Service.

[image: Error Generation Swagger]

In Temp File Create a log give Below

6/21/2022 10:44:14 PM
Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Failed to update your API in Azure (Status code: BadRequest).

at Microsoft.WebTools.Azure.Publish.ApiMApi.BaseApiMApiUpdater.d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.WebTools.Azure.Publish.ApiMApi.AppServiceApiMApiPublishHandler.AppServiceApiMApiUpdater.d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.WebTools.Azure.Publish.ApiMApi.BaseApiMApiUpdater.d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
at Microsoft.WebTools.Azure.Publish.ApiMApi.AppServiceApiMApiPublishHandler.d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
at Microsoft.WebTools.Azure.Publish.PublishProviders.AppServicePublishProfileVisual.d__56.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Publish.Framework.Nexus.PublishProfilesServiceImpl.ServerProjectProfilesManager.d__55.MoveNext()

===================

Answer (score 0):

According to the screenshot information, the process of website publishing has been completed. It's just that swagger.json is not updated.

**By searching this issue, I think there are two alternatives below, which should help you.**

[1. By modifying the configuration, the swagger.json file is generated at compile time. 
(Please modify the path.)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72654660/7687666)

[2. Disable update the api during publish.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70080593/7687666)

Comment: 1. is not working i have tried the same. 2. is working but how to deploy new API changes? new changes are not replicating on azure. any idea?