# Azure Publish generate swagger file fails

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio, swagger

I have an ASPNETCORE App Service that I am trying to publish from Visual Studio.
Swagger code was included by default when I created project from template (ASP.NET Core Web API). The publish to Azure is generally ok, except the swagger gen fails with an error.
However, the failure is NOT actually with swagger but with a database exception (swagger is catching the exception and halting).

Question: what does the command below actually do; and how can I debug what is happening to fix the actual problem (which I suspect is db connection string)?

```
dotnet swagger tofile --output swagger.json $(OutputPath)\$(AssemblyName).dll v1
```

the app service does deploy and run successfully on publish.

I did find [Azure publish: Failed to update API in Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69090118/azure-publish-failed-to-update-api-in-azure/70080593#70080593) helpful; I turned off the UpdateApiOnPublish to get rid of the error.

I also used [Swagger/OpenAPI static file not appearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72647688/swagger-openapi-static-file-not-appearing/72654660#72654660) to add the Post Build command; this helps in that I can replicate the error on Build versus on Publish. It does raise the question of what configuration is swagger using: appsetting.json or appsettings.development.json? is it using the Debug or Release binaries?

UPDATE 1
the runtime swagger gen is actually working, its just the update to swagger.json that is not. so turning off "updateapionpublish" doesnt stop swagger from working.

Update 2: here is the specific code

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString(Constants.STR_SQLConnectionStringName);
if (connectionString == null)
{
    throw new ApplicationException(Constants.STR_ErrorInvalidDBConnectionString);
}

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

// I think exception is being thrown here... but I am not sure.
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(
    options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString)
    );

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddDatasyncControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

if (builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
    {
        options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "v1");
        options.RoutePrefix = "api/docs";
    });
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting ?

Comment: the swagger reports a generic "fail"; that I understand, as there is a runtime error in the code. to be clear, swagger doesnt have an error, its just reporting an error thrown by the code. The code is throwing a database error, most likely from either a connection string not configured or a security/access denied error or database not found error.

Comment: the question is: how is the application being run by swagger? how can I debug what the application is doing when being run by swagger? or am I missing something about how the command "dotnet swagger" works?

Comment: You have created a project in visual studio and connected a data base using connected services and while deploying to azure you are getting some error that is what you are trying to say?

Comment: What is the DB you are connecting to ?

Comment: DB type: running locally (either as iis or https service) connecting to local sql server 2016; deployed to azure connecting to azure sql server. the application runs correctly for both local (on iis express or https) and on azure.

Comment: when publishing from visual studio to azure, the final step is to run swagger to refresh the json file (default behaviour). In my case, the publish to azure succeeds, but the swagger gen fails. if I turn off the swagger gen then the "publish" process is marked as successful. TO BE CLEAR: publish actually works, application actually works, its the swagger gen that fails when "running" the application. My Guess is the swagger gen is not loading the correct app settings so it doesnt have a valid db connection string. That is a Guess. what I want to do is debug the swagger gen and catch/fix it.

Comment: FYI I havent included the specific error message because that is not what I want help with. I want help with figuring out how the swagger gen works and how to diagnose/debug the process when it throws an exception. Once I can do that, I can fix the actual error.

Answer (score 0):

> what does the command below actually do;
>
> ```cs
> dotnet swagger tofile --output swagger.json $(OutputPath)\$(AssemblyName).dll v1
> ```

- This command is used to generate a `Swagger` or `OpenAPI`  file from your application's starting assembly.
- Check the configuration code in `Program.cs`.

As mentioned in the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio)

- Check whether you have any if conditions in `Program.cs` file, which runs only in Local Environment.

***My `Program.cs`:***

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
var app = builder.Build();
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

- Write the below code outside the if condition.

```cs
 app.UseSwagger();
 app.UseSwaggerUI();
```

Refer [GitHub](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore) and  [swagger in asp.net core web api](https://www.pragimtech.com/blog/azure/how-to-use-swagger-in-asp.net-core-web-api/) for more details.

Comment: "runs only in Local Environment": I do have code like the above. But I also have code that throws an Exception (before the IsDevelopment() is checked). my issue is: when swagger tofile is called, which appsettings.json file is being loaded? is there a way for me to control which json file is used?

Comment: Please refer this [Doc](https://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2022/09/aspnet-coregenerate-your-swaggerjson-at.html) once.

Comment: static compile time generation is probably a better approach. will try that out. (BTW I havent seen any MS code samples that use this approach).